# Weird Behaviour in Multidimensional Array Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have a data, for an example like this:

```
{
   "carts":[
      {
         "id":791,
         "name":"CAPE DISCOVERY SHIRAZ",
         "image":"http://example.com/foo.png",
         "price":20000,
         "additionals":[
            [
               {
                  "id":792,
                  "name":"Extra Cheese",
                  "price":20000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":80
               },
               {
                  "id":790,
                  "name":"Extra Beef",
                  "price":30000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":16
               },
               {
                  "id":788,
                  "name":"Extra Mayonnaise",
                  "price":50000,
                  "count":4,
                  "stock":34
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":792,
                  "name":"Extra Cheese",
                  "price":20000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":80
               },
               {
                  "id":790,
                  "name":"Extra Beef",
                  "price":30000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":16
               },
               {
                  "id":788,
                  "name":"Extra Mayonnaise",
                  "price":50000,
                  "count":4,
                  "stock":34
               }
            ]
         ],
         "count":2
      }
   ]
}
```

When I tried to loop the array of `additionals` in order to increase / decrease the `count` attribute by its `id`, the results is all the `count` attribute with the same `id` is affected too.

Here is a method that I use for incrementing and decrementing

```
//Get the last additional of an item then get the correspond additional and increment its count
addAdditional(event, productId, additionalId) {
  let data = this.carts.filter((e) => e.id == productId)[0]?.additionals
  data[data.length - 1].filter(e => e.id == additionalId)[0].count++
  return;
},
//Get the last additional of an item then get the correspond additional and decrement its count
removeAdditional(event, productId, additionalId) {
  let data = this.carts.filter((e) => e.id == productId)[0]?.additionals
  data[data.length - 1].filter((e) => {
    if (e.id == additionalId && e.count > 0) {
      e.count--;
    }
    return e;
  });
},
```

I will explain things further:
productId referring to the key value of 791, and additional ID referring to `id` inside `additionals` attribute. The `count` attribute refers to how much item it trying to purchase. The `count` is synchronized by how much `additionals` are there.

The weird stuff if I, for example, I increment the `count` of `Extra Cheese` by the value of 5, the second item (`Extra Cheese`) in the array is also updating too to value of 5.

Also, it happens when I change the value manually with Vue Devtools.

Comment: do you want to change just one value at a time? in that case you have to provide an index of that particular item in that array. Also please use Vue.set api to set/unset value in array/object so that vue will re render the list .

Comment: Yes, I would like to change one value at a time. Did I not provide index yet? It seems to me I already did. All right, will read and try t, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As this is multidimensional array it's better if you use index to update a particular element. Moreover in your case you have same id in additionals array for multiple element. so to pick one of them to be updated you can't use `id` as they are not unique unless you combine id with it's position index in that array. Hope that make sense.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  methods : {
    changeCountByIndex(cartItemIndex , addParentIndex , itemIndex , type)
    {

       let current_value = this.carts[cartItemIndex].additionals[addParentIndex][itemIndex].count;

       Vue.set(this.carts[cartItemIndex].additionals[addParentIndex][itemIndex] , 'count' , type=== 'add' ? ++current_value : --current_value)
    }
  },
  data: {
   "carts":[
      {
         "id":791,
         "name":"CAPE DISCOVERY SHIRAZ",
         "image":"http://example.com/foo.png",
         "price":20000,
         "additionals":[
            [
               {
                  "id":792,
                  "name":"Extra Cheese",
                  "price":20000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":80
               },
               {
                  "id":790,
                  "name":"Extra Beef",
                  "price":30000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":16
               },
               {
                  "id":788,
                  "name":"Extra Mayonnaise",
                  "price":50000,
                  "count":4,
                  "stock":34
               }
            ],
            [
               {
                  "id":792,
                  "name":"Extra Cheese",
                  "price":20000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":80
               },
               {
                  "id":790,
                  "name":"Extra Beef",
                  "price":30000,
                  "count":0,
                  "stock":16
               },
               {
                  "id":788,
                  "name":"Extra Mayonnaise",
                  "price":50000,
                  "count":4,
                  "stock":34
               }
            ]
         ],
         "count":2
      }
   ]

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="vue-app">
    <div :key="item.id" v-for="(item, cartItemIndex) in carts">
      <strong>
        {{ item.name }}
      </strong>
      
      additionals 
      <div :key="'a' + addParentIndex" v-for="(addItem , addParentIndex) in item.additionals">
      
          <div :key="extra.id" v-for="(extra , itemIndex) in addItem">
              {{ extra.name }} {{extra.count}}  <button @click="changeCountByIndex(cartItemIndex ,addParentIndex , itemIndex , 'add')">+</button> <button @click="changeCountByIndex(cartItemIndex ,addParentIndex , itemIndex , 'decrease')">-</button>
          </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```